# Resolving Directory Symlink in Java

Tags: java, symlink

Given a `File` or `Path` directory object, how do I check if it is a symlink and how do I resolve it to the actual  directory?

I've tried `File.getCannonicalFile()`, `Files.isSymbolicLink(Path)` and many other methods, but none of them seem to work. One interesting thing is that `Files.isDirectory(Path)` returns false, while `Files.exists(Path)` is true. Is java treating the symlink as a file instead of a directory?

Comment: So why doesn't `Files.isSymbolicLink` not working?  What operating system are you on?  Works fine for me on Linux, anyway.

Comment: "None of them seem to work" <-- that is pretty vague. java.nio.file just works in this case. Please show your code.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

If you want to fully resolve a `Path` to point to the actual content, use `.toRealPath()`:

```
final Path realPath = path.toRealPath();
```

This will resolve all symbolic links etc.

However, since this can fail (for instance, a symlink cannot resolve), you'll have to deal with `IOException` here.

Therefore, if you want to test whether a symlink points to an *existing* directory, you will have to do:

```
Files.isDirectory(path.toRealPath());
```

Note a subtlety about `Files.exists()`: by default, **it follows symbolic links**.

Which means that if you have a symbolic link as a `path` whose target does not exist, then:

```
Files.exists(path)
```

will return FALSE; but this:

```
Files.exists(path, LinkOption.NOFOLLOW_LINKS)
```

will return TRUE.

In "Unix parlance", this is the difference between `stat()` and `lstat()`.