# List *all* files in a directory with Java (even invalid ones)

Tags: java, posix

I need to get a list of all files that exist in a directory including broken symlinks and other entries that would be considered invalid by `File.listFiles()`.

I tried multiple different ways of listing files in Java and all of them seem to discard "invalid" files.

To reproduce this issue:

```bash
# Create a symlink to a nonexistent path
ln -s /nonexistent/path $PWD/broken_link

# Create a valid symlink
ln -s /path/to/existing/file $PWD/working_link

# Create a normal file
touch empty_file
```

```java
var files = new File(".").listFiles();

Arrays.stream(files).forEach(file -> {
  System.out.println(file.getName();
});
```

Expected output (in no particular order):

```
broken_link
working_link
empty_file
```

Actual output:

```
working_link
empty_file
```

Considering the nature of Java, a multiplatform solution would be ideal but reallistically I only need this to work on POSIX systems (namely macOS and Linux) but I would like to avoid any kind of external dependencies (such as parsing th eoutput of `ls`, using JNI, etc).

Comment: In other words, what is an "invalid" file? How can I create one to reproduce? I'm afraid if the standard ways do not work out of the box, you will eventually need to do one of the other solutions you want to avoid, like parsing `ls`.

Comment: For dealing with symlinks, see: [Resolving Directory Symlink in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28371993), [How to read a symlink file in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75086985).

Comment: The issue cannot be reproduced on linux 5.10.74-gentoo with openjdk version "1.8.0_332", see https://pastebin.com/xDmkDczH. Please [edit] your question to include the version numbers you have on your system.

Comment: What does `File.list()` give you?

Comment: Cannot reproduce with openjdk 17.0.5 on Ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS. Both `new File(".").listFiles()` and `Files.list()` show all three files (broken, working and empty).